# Como tirar o botão de um input file (sem JS)

Tags: html, css, input, file-upload

Tenho o seguinte `input file` e queria saber como tirar o botão, para que na caixa mostre apenas o nome do arquivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Não é necessário JS, já vi alguns exemplos e lembro que não usavam JS, mas também não lembro qual foi o modo utilizado.

Comment: @MuriloGambôa realmente está duplicada, e [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90583/35406) tem a resposta para sua pergunta, mantendo o nome do arquivo como você quer.

Comment: Notar que as respostas dadas na outra pergunta produzem o resultado final simulando a caixa de texto, pois o conjunto do botão com a caixa original são indivisíveis nas atuais especificações. Mas lá você encontra a solução do label separado, como mencionou, e como fazer a "caixinha" de texto pra substituir a original.

Comment: Tem aqui alguns exemplos dum plugin bootstrap: [basic](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo) e [advanced](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-advanced-usage-demo)

Comment: Pra facilitar o entendimento do fechamento por duplicata: Se fossemos considerar "literalmente" a pergunta, a única resposta válida seria "não existe como fazer", então ao menos foi apontado um jeito de contornar a situação. Na especificação, o botão com a caixa foi concebido como um controle só, e qualquer coisa que aja separadamente nos elementos é liberalidade do _vendor_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu faria assim utilizando bootstrap

Parte 1. HTML

```
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary"> 
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input type="file" class="upload" /> 
</div>
```

Parte 2. CSS

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 10px; 
}
.fileUpload input.upload { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    opacity: 0; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
}
```

Sem botstrap dá para fazer assim:

```css
/* CSS */
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<label class="custom-file-upload">
  <input type="file"/>
  Clique aqui para upload
</label>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54238/discussion-on-answer-by-ack-lay-como-tirar-o-botao-de-um-input-file-sem-js)